# How would I convert a char array to int?

Tags: c++, char

So the input file looks like this:

```
Adam Zeller 45231 78 86 91 64 90 76 
Barbara Young 274253 88 77 91 66 82 93 
Carl Wilson 11223 87 77 76 78 77 82
```

SIZE = 256;

I used the `getline` function to put the first line into char `lineOne[SIZE]` and the others lines in `lineTwo[SIZE]` and `lineThree[SIZE]` but I need to be able to modify the last 5 numbers in each line, like reorder them and such. How would I go about doing this? I don't think I could convert the whole char array to an int because it has not only integers in the line and I don't really know what to do, I am stuck.

Also I can't use the string library.

Comment: Are there always going to be seven numbers following the name?

Comment: Will there always be three lines?

Comment: Oh. I read "string library" and thought C++ string. Do you mean the C string library is off limits? If that's the case, then you should use `fscanf()` with `%d` in the appropriate places. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: @Code-Guru no there could be whatever

Comment: @kmort Actually I can use the <cstring> library, just not <string>

Comment: @MattRay Then you need to use a loop rather than three separate array variables.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're going to use [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to "tokenize" your line of input. This means it will split it into chunks. You'll make it split at the spaces of course.

As long as your data follows the pattern you have above, you can skip the first two, then use [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) to convert from ASCII to integers.

Store these integers in an array, and you can do what you like with them.

Some rough pseudocode for getting the values you want could look like this:

```
char *ptr;
    for each line
    {
       ptr=strtok(lineOne," "); // do the initial strtok with a pointer to your string. 
       //At this point ptr points to the first name
       for(number of things in the line using an index variable)
       {
           ptr=strtok(NULL," "); // at this point ptr points to the last name
           if(index==0)
              {
              continue;  //causes the for loop to skip the rest and go to the next iteration 
              }
           else
              {
              ptr=strtok(NULL," "); // at this point ptr points to one of the integer values, 
                                 //index=1 being the first one.... (careful not to get off by one here)
              int value=atoi(ptr)
              /// stuff the value into your array... etc...
              storageArray[index-1]=value; /// or something like this
              .....
              }    
       }
    }
```

Comment: How would I "skip" the first two?

Comment: @MattRay Skip the first two in your loop by explicitly testing for `index==0` and `index==1`. Don't use `atoi()` on these, nor add them to your storage array/struct/whatever storage type you choose. Basically, since you know the format of the data, you can count the number of tokens to get to the right place before you start using `atoi()`.

Comment: I'm sorry but when I write the strtok function how would I skip the first two? Like what would the code look like? @kmort

Comment: @MattRay No problems. I updated the answer with some rough pseudocode. You'll have some to fill in, but this should give you the idea. Also, I wasn't sure if you wanted to skip the first two or first three values. The pseudocode I wrote only skips 2, but you can easily make it skip more.

Comment: Sweet okay, now at what part does the strtok() function go? lol sorry I'm a little new @kmort

Answer (score 0):

As one of the other answers suggests, I would use `strtok()` to tokenize the input, but I would also implement a simple struct to hold each record.  Then use a do-while loop to read in each line, split the line into tokens, and read it into a record.

Comment: Okay so according to my input file I would make the struct variables like this? first_name, last_name, id, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5?

Comment: Sure - or just use an array for the numbers